# Centralize popup related to home screen width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, css-transitions

I have created popups and linked them in footer I want when user click and popup appeares it should centered to my screen horizontally and vertically no matter its large or small screen. and nothing can be clickable till popup remains. Now the issue is my popup centered to the full page height not the current screen height

```
.popup .content{
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%)scale(0);
    background: white;
    color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: justify;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 32px;
}
```

[image: popup]

Answer (score 1):

You can centralized your popup by removing scale from  transform property.

Comment: but this transform property used in show and hide my popup if i removed scale popup cross button is not working to close the popup

Comment: you can do this by using display property. Using display: none you can Hide your popup

Comment: okay thanks I'll try this.